# Unfold chart of account view in openerp?

Tags: odoo

Does any one know how to make the char of account or any of the list view to appear as unfold by default?

Answer (score 1):

This features was taking so long (balance calculation on each account) in previous versions (v5) that OpenERP remove the functionality.